# How do I append to python subdict array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, dictionary

I want to print something like the following but I don't know how to add/append to the python dict array.

```
slots = [{
     "court_name": "court 1",
     "bookings": [{
          "start_time": "8pm"
     }]
},
{
     "court_name": "court 2",
     "bookings": [{
          "start_time": "8pm"
     },
     {
          "start_time": "9pm"
     }]
}]
```

I have a bunch of booking slots and I want to render them like above using a for loop. How do I append/add objects to the dict as what I am trying doesn't work?

```
slots = {}
prev_court = -1
for booking in instances_sorted:
            this_court = booking['location_id']
            if this_court == prev_court: # court is the same
                slots[len(slots)-1]["slots"].append({
                    "start_time": booking.start_time,
                })
            else: # new court
                slots.append{
                    "court_name": booking.location__court_name,
                    "slots" : [{
                        "start_time": booking.start_time,
                    }]
                }
            prev_court = this_court
```

I feel like this should be pretty simple but couldn't find anything great when I searched for similar answers. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What list are you trying to append to?

Comment: Trying to append to the slots dict and then append to the slots["slots"] list?

Comment: Most of what you have is OK.  It's just that the second call to append should be `slots.append({`, not just `slots.append{`, and the close should be `})` not `}`.

Comment: I gave that a shot (FYI I am using Django) and it is saying "'dict' object has no attribute 'append'"

Comment: Okay, so. In the example output you showed, you wanted `slots` to be a list, right? and the intended approach for your code is to start with an empty list, and either update the existing elements, or append new ones, right? So - does the code in fact start with an empty list? What does `slots = {}` mean?

Comment: Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. It's expected that you are able to figure out trivial issues with code like this yourself, by reading the error messages, understanding what went wrong, and diagnosing possible causes. If you get stuck, you should ask a *specific* question that references the [*complete* error message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough), explain the results of your debugging effort so far, and explain exactly why you are confused.

Comment: No I want slots to be a dictionary. slots = {} is declaring slots as a dict. Yes I want to append to this dict, I don't want to update existing stuff. The code starts with an empty dict.

Answer (score 1):

`update()` method adds element(s) to the dictionary if the key is not in the dictionary. If the key is in the dictionary, it updates the key with the new value.

Comment: Thanks that has cleared passed the else statement part for slots but getting errors on the if statement. It's stating "KeyError: 1" where I have slots[len(slots)-1]["slots"].update({
                    "start_time": booking.start_time,
                })

Answer (score 1):

Issue I was having was that I declared slots as a dict when in fact it is a list. So the solution would look something like this.

```
slots = []
prev_court = -1
N = 0
for booking in instances_sorted:
    this_court = booking['location_id']
    if this_court == prev_court: # court is the same
        N = N + 1
        slots[N]["slots"].append({
            "start_time": booking.start_time,
        })
    else: # new court
        slots.append({
            "court_name": booking.location__court_name,
            "slots" : [{
                "start_time": booking.start_time,
             }]
         })
    prev_court = this_court
```